# trying to split csv keep getting 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split' error

Tags: python, csv, split, classification

I'm trying to build a dict for my image classifier, however when i keep trying to each line of my csv I'm getting a "Dataframe has no attribute split" error

```
naimg_dict = {} 
f = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['training.csv']))
fileContents = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['training.csv']))
fileContents = fileContents.split('\n') #This is where I get the error

for i in range(len(fileContents)-1):
  fileContents[i] = fileContents[i].split(',')
  naming_dict[fileContents[i][0]] = fileContents[i][1]
```

Comment: pd.read_csv returns a Pandas DataFrame, not a string.
You should read about that...
Are you trying to have access to your file lines ?

Comment: your question is not well formulated also. Can you explain better what you want to do please?

Comment: use `print(fileContents)` to see that you have table with rows and columns. You don't have to split it.

Comment: yes Furas is right, though it could be easier to understand what's going on with ```print(fileContents.head())``` - this will print the first 5 rows.

Comment: for training ML probably you could get `X = fileContents[1:]` and `Y = fileContents[0]` and use in `fit(X, Y)`

Comment: sorry if i my qquestion was unclear, I'm trying to acces each line of the csv, which contains training data; hence the for-loop. godot, are you saying I should I convert the csv to a string before using .split()?